# Implement a back button for multi-page form (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Users can register for the website. When they do, it is a three page process. I implemented this by saving the new data to one user DB entry after each page, then storing the user ID in session and fetching at at the next page. I have been trying to find a way to implement a back button so the user can go back and redo their details.

The front end for all three pages is just a typical form structure

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form"  method="POST" action="{{ url('/step/2') }}">
     <!--fields here-->
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

The back end for each stage looks like this:

Page 1

```
 public function submitFirst(Request $request)
 {
     // create user 
     // put data into user
     // save user
     // redirect to second page
 }
```

Page 2

```
 public function submitTwo(Request $request)
 {
     // Fetch user from session
     // put data into user
     // save user
     // redirect to third page
 }
```

Page 3

```
 public function submitTwo(Request $request)
 {
     // Fetch user from session
     // put data into user
     // save user
     // redirect to login
 }
```

However, if I go back to the first page and fill it in again it will simply create a new user instead of modifying the fields of the current user.

I am wondering what the best solution would be.

Comment: Your Question is not clear actually what you want?

Comment: your provided code is not helpful for solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine something like the following on each of the methods would work:

```
public function submitFirst(Request $request) {
    if($request->session()->has('user_id')){ //If user_id exists in session
        $user = User::find(session);
    }else{
        $user = new User;
    }
    $user->name="blah blah";
    //rest of the user fields
    $user->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once first form is submitted you can probably store UserId in the session.
And when you navigate back to first page you can use the below logic

```
 public function submitFirst(Request $request)
{
      $id = \Session::get('user_id');
      $user = User::where('id','=',$id)->first;
      if($user == null){
         // create user
         // put data into user
          \Session::put('user_id', $user->id);/*user id of the newly created user*/
      }else{
         // edit existing user
      }  
     // save user
     // redirect to second page
 }
```